# Images are showing in Chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: html, css, asp.net, image, iis

The url of the site I am talking is `https://example.org/visitors/home.aspx` The images are showing properly only in Chrome, even it is not showing in incognito. Everything seems fine to me while inspecting from the browser. The site is hosted on a vps using `iis 10`. Can someone please check and guide me to resolve the issue?

The weird thing is, it works perfectly when using without ssl `http://example.org/visitors/home.aspx` in both Chrome & Firefox !

Comment: The site looks the same to me on Chrome and Firefox (Windows 10) - all images seem to be showing.

Comment: @AHaworth Really? That's weird, can you please also check in incognito?

Comment: your png files are broken - how you make them ?

Comment: Images don't work for me on firefox anyway, when I inspect it's telling me that images contain errors

Comment: I can’t see your picture when I use chrome. Is it possible that the path of the photo is changed? You can try to relink the picture. This is the reference link that the firefox browser image cannot display: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/fix-problems-images-not-show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting the solution I found finally which might help others for similar issue. The `PNG` images is also showing perfectly in `https` if they are modified somehow. For testing, I just opened and saved as same image with `ms paint` without any changes. So I made a small C# program which does this to all(25474) the `PNG` images and all the `PNG` images are showing fine now while using `SSL`